# Change logo image when I switch to a different language

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have this multilingual website. Is there a way I can change the logo.png to a different .png after I switch to "Chinese?"

I am using polylang plugin at the moment and this is what I have scrummed together:

```
$(function() {


if (pll_current_language == 'en') {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
} else if (pll_current_language == 'zh') {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo-CN.png)");  
} else {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
}
});
```

Comment: I have same issue . Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
if (pll_current_language == 'en') {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
} else if (pll_current_language == 'zh') {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo-CN.png)");  
} else {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
}
```

to

```
if (pll_current_language() == 'en') {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
} else if (pll_current_language() == 'zh') {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo-CN.png)");  
} else {
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
}
```

should work, you are missing the "()" after "pll_current_language"

EDIT: Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
<?php
if (pll_current_language() == 'en') {
?>
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
<?php
} else if (pll_current_language() == 'zh') {
?>
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo-CN.png)");  
<?php
} else {
?>
    $('.logo').css("background-image", "url(images/logo.png)");  
<?php
}
?>
});
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I tried the method you mentioned and it didn't work :(

https://www.medicinebuddhahill.com/home/

Comment: Try my edit. You were trying to mix php and javascript.

Comment: Where do I paste that? In my js file? Currently, I have my code in my js file.

Comment: You can't use php in a js file. You will probably need to add that to the header.php file.

Comment: I just did. And this is what I'm getting:

https://www.medicinebuddhahill.com/home/

Btw, thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: I did that as well. Nothing happens :(

Comment: That should work, can you post what you tried that time (as an edit to your question)